# UMTS Architecture and differences between releases

Tags: mobile

I am studying the evolution of mobile network technologies and trying to get a clear overview of the UMTS network achitecture.

However, I found it hard to decide which release of UMTS is considered its "latest" and more appropriate to work on. By "appropriate" I mean most commonly deployed and/or usually studied by people that want to gain an understanding of UMTS.

Is it Release 99, in which UMTS is introduced?
Or maybe Release 7, the last one before LTE?
Or, maybe another release?

Additionally, is it a good idea to think of HSPA(+), simply as an enhanced version of UMTS?

Furthermore, when looking for a clear overview of what changed in the architecture between the releases the information was poor. Of course, there is always the 3GPP specifications webpage but I found it hard to follow, as a rookie.

Comment: This question seems to be about which [UMTS Release](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Mobile_Telecommunications_System#Releases) is appropriate to work on; however, there are no guidelines for how appropriate is evaluated. If you can make the question less subjective, we can consider reopening.

Comment: You probably want release 8.

Comment: @killiands why do you recommend release 8?

Comment: @MikePennington, basically it's the last release that did any real additions to the UMTS standards as far as I know. UMTS work in later releases is more about finetuning/errata and interop interfaces with 4G 3GPP networks. You can always just use Release 11 (or even 12), but 8 should be enough. Additionally, I know from industry experience that for GGSN interop testing release 8 is usually used as the base for comparison.

Comment: @killiands could you add this as an answer?